# How to conditionally disable cart sidebar components

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I want to disable a UI component conditionally in the cart sidebar.
I could do it as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="minicart">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="item.renderer" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="checkout.cart.item.price.sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

But that isn't condittionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is using a JsLayoutProvider (**or you can also add a layouthandle and disable components in the layout xml**). Here you can adjust the parsed layout xml files as an multidim array.

First you need a class which implements the `Magento\Customer\CustomerData\JsLayoutDataProviderInterface` class. In this class you need a getData method which returns the array of layout you want to adjust.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Vendor\Module\CustomerData;

use Magento\Customer\CustomerData\JsLayoutDataProviderInterface;
use Vendor\Module\Helper\Data;

/**
 * Checkout totals js layout data provider
 */
class HidePricesJsLayoutDataProvider implements JsLayoutDataProviderInterface
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        $hidePrices = $this->hidepricesHelper->getHidePrices();
        return [
            'components' => [
                'minicart_content' => [
                    'children' => [
                        'item.renderer' => [
                            'children' => [
                                'checkout.cart.item.price.sidebar' => [
                                    'config' => [
                                        'componentDisabled' => true
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Then you need to declare a virtualtype in your frontend/di.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\CustomerData\JsLayoutDataProviderPoolInterface">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayoutDataProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="hide_prices" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\CustomerData\HidePricesJsLayoutDataProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Now your JsLayoutDataProvider will be added & merged to the layout xml data in the constructor of `Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar`

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper,
    \Magento\Customer\CustomerData\JsLayoutDataProviderPoolInterface $jsLayoutDataProvider,
    array $data = [],
    \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $serializer = null
) {
    if (isset($data['jsLayout'])) {
        $jsLayoutData=$jsLayoutDataProvider->getData();
        $this->jsLayout = $this->array_merge_recursive_distinct($jsLayoutData, $data['jsLayout']);
        unset($data['jsLayout']);
    } else {
        $this->jsLayout = $jsLayoutDataProvider->getData();
    }
```